# Prevent MSIE 8 from reloading PAC file

Tags: internet-explorer-8, pac

How do I prevent Internet Explorer from reloading the PAC file? I need to stop IE8 from reloading the PAC file on every request the browser makes.

I only require it to load once per session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this behaviour before. The only thing that comes to mind is that caching of proxy autoconfiguration (PAC) scripts might be disabled. Even so, I wasn't aware that disabling such caching caused the script to be loaded more than once per browser session.

The setting is configurable via Group Policy at: User Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Internet Explorer / Disable caching of Auto-Proxy scripts

In the registry, the policy setting lives at: `HKCR\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\EnableAutoProxyResultCache`

Comment: Thanks Evan, I'll poke around the registry shortly and get back to all here asap with the results. I do remember playing around with cache settings, but not PAC cache in particular.